# Adjust size based on height (vertical length)

Tags: css

I am doing a div that needs to display the whole content of a text field and adjust the text size dynamically so that it will not overflow.

To get an idea of the problem, look here http://sandbox.littlegraffyx.com/bible/

You can try entering verses at lower left text box using the format `GEN 1:1` for "Genesis 1:1"

My problem is when I try to display long verses, they get truncated. I need to change the size based on how long the current text is. Is there some css that can be applied based on text field size?

Comment: will you like to have a jQuery code?

Comment: The problem is many, but for starters, you're using IDs on elements where you intend to have classes (ID should always be unique per element, never repeated). Additionally, you should be using the CSS box model to your benefit, not fighting it.

Comment: Thanks.. Actually I am just starting to kick off and I really don't have idea what I am using. just whatever i found on the net. for box model. are you referring to this?

Comment: @shahbaz what changes do i need to make? do i need to start over? I hope not but if there's no other way I am willing to consider any solution that will work

Comment: You can't do this purely with CSS. You would need to use javascript, and jquery library would be make it easy, though not a necessary one.

Comment: @CharlesWayne can you please clarify if your issue if to do with the size of the text input field (see Anonymous' answer below), or to do with the size of the text itself (the verse displayed in large white text after submitting the form)? I assumed the latter (see my answer below), but perhaps I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it isn't possible to scale text based on the height of its containing element using pure CSS. But here's a small jQuery script I have used in the past when I needed to achieve what you want. It also adjusts the text size when the user resizes the browser window.

HTML:

```
<p class="quote">
Really long text goes here...
</p>​
```

CSS:

```
.quote {
    // The largest size to display text at.
    font-size: 36px;
}​
```

JS:

```
$(window).bind('resize',function(e){
    scaleQuote();
});

function scaleQuote(){    
    var quote = $('.quote');
    var winH = $(window).height();

    // Reset font size.
    quote.css('font-size', '');

    // If quote is larger than viewport, reduce font-size until it fits.
    while (winH < (quote.height())){
        var fontSize = parseInt(quote.css('font-size'), 10);
        quote.css('font-size', fontSize-1+'px');
    }
}

scaleQuote();​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eCBmc/2/

Comment: I'm curious: why the downvote? Is it because I provided a JS solution, or is my answer deficient in some respect? A comment will allow me to address any problems with my answer.

Comment: This is great. This is exactly what I need. Unfortunately I am unable to apply it on my project. Can you check what is wrong? Here is my test page. http://sandbox.littlegraffyx.com/bible/test.html

Comment: I forgot to mention. try to enter "gen 2:19" in the lower left text box to show enough text content.

Comment: @Jonathn Nicol, Is it possible to apply the check in size when div changes as well? it resizes perfectly on window change but I realize my text content changes using next previous button. http://sandbox.littlegraffyx.com/bible/test.html

Comment: After populating #versePlace with the new text, call the scaleQuote() function. e.g. after document.getElementById("versePlace").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

Comment: @Jonathn Nicol, I put it there but it seems the height of the div is not updated immediately because scaleQuote is being run when leaving the current verse. on the test page try to go to 1ki 6:31. When you click next, 6:31 will be scaled then it will move to next verse 1ki6:32. What's happening is the verse is being scaled just before it leaves the verse not upon showing the verse. I tried moving scalequote function around with no luck.

Comment: @Jonathn Nicol, I got it. I print the javascript call along with the div updates that happens on my php file that fulls the verse content from the database. Thanks for bringing up this idea to solve the problem. Great help! Here is the final working. (old testament only (yet)) http://sandbox.littlegraffyx.com/bible/test2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. It will set input field to 10 character, and if it's bigger it increase it's size.
http://jsfiddle.net/4qjjf/1/

```
<html>
<body>
<textarea cols="10" rows="1" id="shit"
onkeyup="this.cols=this.value.length>10?this.value.length:10;"></textarea>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: The OP wants to change the size of the large white text (the verses), NOT the form input.